# ANTLR lexer token not being used

Tags: python-3.x, antlr4

I have this small example, trying to parse a `key:value` type string (real examples may be more complex, but I want to essentially have a `[a-zA-Z0-9]` style string then a colon, then whatever else on that line to be the value (not including the colon)
https://gist.github.com/nmz787/4888cfadf707a575de0662f8a3914ce0

Unfortunately it isn't working, the `INTERMEDIATE` lexer token is not being found... I just can't figure it out. This is a really simple example extracted from a more complex parser and lexer that I've been handed to work on adding more features to. So I hope it's sufficient for this forum.

Comment: Hi Bart, yes there are other rules happening too... but they don't seem to be interacting with these. Isn't there a way to FORCE the INTERMEDIATE rule to be used, or if it isn't present, leave the mode? I want ALL my rules to be used, with no flexibility in choosing one over another.

Comment: someone here who knows a bit about ANTLR said I should look into "predicates". Basically I am not understanding why there is some flexibility in ANTLR picking and choosing which rules to process or ignore... like, I listed ALL the lexer rules I wanted to require the parser rule to use... why does it ignore INTERMEDIATE when I specifically call it out? If it would consume them in the order I wrote, then it would find it, and then the next rule would gobble up the rest of the line (my intention). Being greedy is fine, but only AFTER the earlier rule.

Comment: I changed the lexer rule to be `COLON_ATTRIBUTES_DATA: ~[:] ~[\r\n]+;` and the original input now works, but adding another line to the input `key.subkey: a:b:c` fails with  these messages `line 1:5 missing COLON_ATTRIBUTES_INTERMEDIATE at 'value'` and `line 1:10 mismatched input '\nkey.subkey: a:b:c' expecting COLON_ATTRIBUTES_END`

Answer (score 1):

Using ANTLR4 to parse a key/value store is pretty much over-the-top. All you would need is to split your input into individual lines. Then split each line at the colon, trim the resulting strings and there you have it. No need for a parser at all.

Comment: there's a lot more happening in the parser/lexer... I just slimmed things down so I could post the example without leaking the company's info